# Converting Word to PDF Using SharePoint 2010 Word Automation Services

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, word-automation

I have tried to find out the way I can put locks or disable the copy and paste on the PDF file after the conversion. I looked at the ConversionJobSettings properties but I couldn’t be able to accomplish this.
Based on what I have read, the sharepoint2010 Word Automation services API provides very limited capability in manipulating the conversion logics but is there any way I can lock down the content so that it cannot be copied?

Thank for your help

Answer (score 1):

You will either need to code something up yourself or get a [third party product such as this one](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/12/securing-pdf-files-using-sharepoint.html), which allows conversion as well as PDF manipulation including security and watermarking.

Note that I worked on this product, so I am obviously biased. Having said that, it works brilliantly.

Comment: Thanks Muhimbi. The product looks great based on the description and it is really good to know what is out there but the third party product is not my option right now. Could you guide me on how to accomplish this through word Automation API or any other way? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, but this is not possible using the Word Automation API.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to prevent copy and paste (as text) is to create image versions of the pages and saves those as a PDF.

a possible solution:

1) Use Word automation to print to a PostScript (PS) printer driver to get a .ps file

2) Use GhostScript to convert the PS to tif files

3) Create a PDF using the tif files (possibly with GhostScript too)

Comment: Wow thanks Mark. Everything you said is so new to me and sound good so I have to search and find out how to do these in relation to sharepoint2010 environment. Is there any material that I should refer to? Thanks